# Can't delete files using a Dropbox Business team token

Tags: dropbox-api

the following code should work, shouldn't it?

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/delete_v2"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <access-token>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Dropbox-Api-Select-Admin": 
    "dbmid:AADnRVGZHenLtFbLVdHDkqEJg3Dou4hWF4g"
}

data = {"path": "id:Kd_cXYig9pAAAAAAAAAARQ"}

print(requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)).content)
```

returns:

```
{"error_summary": "path_lookup/not_found/", "error": {".tag": "path_lookup", "path_lookup": {".tag": "not_found"}}}
```

Tried using Dropbox-Api-Select-User, and delete(v1) and permanently_delete and all failed with the same error.

FYI download worked.
(only with Select-Admin, but worked).

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Delete-does-not-work-on-files/m-p/297511#M18051 ]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Greg.
Added "Dropbox-Api-Path-Root" header with the parent_shared_folder_id and the api call worked!

```
headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer f7I8uYSFpxAAAAAAAAAFSs-VIz17DnoqmEYXp0MeitxIzXBCYCT4v0Bb4N4_cbxK",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Dropbox-Api-Path-Root": "{\".tag\": \"namespace_id\", \"namespace_id\": \"2857852064\"}",
"Dropbox-Api-Select-Admin": "dbmid:AADnRVGZHenLtFbLVdHDkqEJg3Dou4hWF4g"
}
```